# Minitest causing issue while deploying through capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, digital-ocean

I am unable to deploy on the staging server (digital ocean) with capistrano due to the below error:

```
[b8eebe47] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.2 /usr/bin/env sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_project_staging restart )
DEBUG[b8eebe47]     Couldn't reload, starting 'cd /home/deploy/project_staging/current;  bundle exec unicorn -D -c /home/deploy/project_staging/shared/config/unicorn.rb -E staging' instead
DEBUG[b8eebe47]
DEBUG[b8eebe47]     [31mCould not find minitest-5.4.2 in any of the sources[0m
DEBUG[b8eebe47]
DEBUG[b8eebe47]     [33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.[0m
DEBUG[b8eebe47]
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: sudo exit status: 7
sudo stdout: Nothing written
sudo stderr: Nothing written
/Users/simmibadhan/Workspace/project/lib/capistrano/tasks/restart.cap:6:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/simmibadhan/Workspace/project/lib/capistrano/tasks/restart.cap:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: sudo exit status: 7
sudo stdout: Nothing written
sudo stderr: Nothing written
/Users/simmibadhan/Workspace/project/lib/capistrano/tasks/restart.cap:6:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/simmibadhan/Workspace/project/lib/capistrano/tasks/restart.cap:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => deploy:restart
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: sudo exit status: 7
sudo stdout: Nothing written
sudo stderr: Nothing written
```

ruby - 2.1.2
rails - 4.1.4

```
gem list minitest

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

minitest (5.4.2, 4.7.5)
```

when I try to uninstall minitest older version, it gives error:

```
gem uninstall minitest -v 4.7.5
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "minitest" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps and was able to deploy successfully.

1. deleted gemfile.lock from my local machine
2. deleted gemfile.lock from current folder on the staging server
3. bundle install on local
4. commit and push Gemfile.lock to git repository
5. cap staging deploy (deploy on staging server using capistrano)